# MYSQL Trigger when a order is inserted a notification inserted into another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called Order and when a order gets inserted into it i want it to insert the sellerID(userID in the notifications) and productName combined with a message to be stored in Notification.Message.

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (
 `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`productID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`productName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`productPrice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`SellerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`BuyerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`DateSold` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`),

 );


CREATE TABLE `Notifications` (
`NotificationID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userID` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Viewed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`NotificationID`);
```

They are my two tables 
This is what i tried:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER productTrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON Order FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
 DECLARE ui,pn VARCHAR(50);

 SELECT productName INTO pn FROM Order;
 SELECT userID INTO ui FROM Product;
 INSERT INTO Notifications(userID,Message) VALUES(ui,pn);

end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `productTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `Order`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  /*DECLARE ui,pn VARCHAR(50);

  SELECT productName INTO pn FROM Order;
  SELECT userID INTO ui FROM Product;
  INSERT INTO Notifications(userID,Message) VALUES(ui,pn);*/

  INSERT INTO `Notifications`
    (`userID`, `Message`)
  VALUES
    (NEW.`SellerID`, NEW.`productName`);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```